# How to prove $\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty a_j^2$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $a_j >0$, j=1,2,3.,,, be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty a_j b_j < \infty$ for every sequence of positive numbers $b_j>0$ which satisfy $\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty b_j^2< \infty$. Prove $\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty a_j^2< \infty$. That is, prove that $\Sigma_{j=1}^\infty a_j^2$ converges.

How to prove this statement?

Comment: Uniform Bounded Principle on $l^2$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this concept. Can we use different method?

Comment: I work out the details for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the Hilbert space $l^{2}$ with the usual inner product.
For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $T_{n}:l^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
by $T_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}x_{k}$, where $x=(x_{k})$. Clearly
$T_{n}$ is linear. Moreover, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|T_{n}(x)|\leq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{2}}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}}||x||$.
Therefore $T_{n}$ is a bounded linear functional. Consider the family
of bounded linear functionals $\{T_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Let
$x\in l^{2}$ be arbitrary. We go tho show that $\{T_{n}(x)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$
is bounded. Let $y=(y_{n})$ be defined by $y_{n}=|x_{n}|$, then
$y\in l^{2}$. By assumption (if $y_n=0$, we may replace it with $1/n$), we have that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}y_{k}<\infty.$
For each $n$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
|T_{n}(x)| & = & \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}x_{k}\right|\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}|x_{k}|\\
 & \leq & \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}y_{k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This show that $\{T_{n}(x)\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is bounded. By Uniform
Boundedness Principle, there exists $M>0$ such that $||T_{n}||\leq M$
for all $n$. On the other hand, put $x=(a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{n},0,0\ldots)$,
then $x\in l^{2}.$ Therefore $|T_n(x)|\leq||T_{n}||\cdot||x||\leq M||x||$.
That is,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2} & \leq & M\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}},
\end{eqnarray*}
which implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}^{2}\leq M^{2}$. Since $n$
is arbitrary, it follows that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}^{2}\leq M<\infty$.